# 'Parse Issue' 'Expected Expression' in probably a bad practice IF statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm sure this code is very bad practice, I don't know I'm still new to this, I was just trying to work out a way this would work but I keep being thrown an error 'Parse Issue' 'Expected Expression'.

```
if ((firstLabel == nil) && ([theArray objectAtIndex:0] == char A||char B||
char C||char D||char E||char F||char G||char H||char I||char J||char K||
char L||char M||char N||char O||char P||char Q||char R||char S||char T||
char U||char V||char W||char X||char Y||char Z))
    {
        [firstLabel setText:[theArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    };
```

Comment: it isn't very readable ...

Comment: alsways try to make it readable and errors will go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to check if the character is a,b,c,d,..
if theArray is an NSArray, it cannot hold chars, so I assume NSStrings

if so syntax is

```
... [theArray objectAtIndex:0] == @"A" || [theArray objectAtIndex:0] == @"B" || [theArray objectAtIndex:0] == @"C"
```

but way nicer:

```
if(theArray.count) {
    id str = @"ABCDEFGHI"; //allowed
    id needle = [theArray objectAtIndex:0];
    if([str rangeOfString:needle].location!=NSNotFound) { 
        //its in!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a characterset and check based on that:

```
NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTWXYZ"];
unichar c = [theArray objectAtIndex:0];
if ((firstLabel == nil) && [myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
{
  [firstLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[theArray objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initialising 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short' with an expression of type 'id' :/

Comment: what does theArray contain? an array of NSStrings?

Comment: put a breakpoint at the side of the NSCharacterSet and execute line by line, then u will see which line is the problem?